# What kind of publication is/was the "Imperial Herald"?

Tags: product-identification, l5r

While skimming through the Legends of the 5 rings fandom-wiki, I found the page for the [court system](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Court_(judicial_system)). It references a source:

> "Way of the Magistrate" Written by Scott Gearin and published in the *Imperial Herald*.

I was not able to find out what kind of publication the *Imperial Herald* is or was, and my google-Fu fails me by using just the term - it gives me too much unrelated stuff. I do know that it is not a 4E splatbook for sure though, so I need help trying to find out what this actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A Magazine

The (rather brief) [L5R fandom wiki page on Scott Gearin](https://l5r.fandom.com/wiki/Scott_Gearin) includes the description:

> Scott Gearin was a fan of the Legend of the Five Rings whose work The Way of the Magistrate was published in the Imperial Herald Magazine #10.

According to the [rpggeek](https://rpggeek.com/rpgperiodical/4669/imperial-herald) entry it is (or was; the last listed issue is from 2011) a quarterly publication as part of a subscription based fan club:

> This is a quarterly publication produced by Alderac Entertainment Group to support the various Legend of the Five Rings game lines. Included are rules updates, previews of upcoming releases, works of fiction set in Rokugan, details of tournaments, interviews with related individuals, and other such relevant articles.
>
> The magazine is available to members of the Imperial Assembly, the official fan club for Legend of the Five Rings, as part of the subscription fees.

In case you're interested, the specific issue appears to be available on [Noble Knight Games' store](https://www.nobleknight.com/P/2147745789/10-Factions-of-Rokugan-Way-of-the-Magistrate).